# How do I scale a GIF to the screen size? (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, 2d

I'm trying to have a GIF as my background, using this code: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10351&p=46673#p46673

I managed to get it to display but it's small and I want it to cover the whole screen. I have looked around but can't seem to find anything in LibGDX, does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion, 
If you have only used that link, the code never mentioned to use a camera.
the default camera being used is an Orthographic camera

And indeed Orthographic Cameras are good for your gif display

Read more about Orthographic cameras [in the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera)

You can get a ton of information off of [the libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki)

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

If you used the code referenced on that link, the draw method also accepts a float width and float height parameter. Try this:

```
batch.draw(anim.getKeyFrame(frameCounter, true),200, 200, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

The last 2 parameters are the width and height of your image, or whatever size you want it to be. That will get the total width and height of your display in pixels, but you should probably use a camera depending on what you're trying to do and leave the scaling calculations to libgdx.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling GIF is no different than scaling any other image in LibGDX. 
You are using a SpriteBatch to draw the Texture so the easiest way to do this woulde be to provide Screen Width and Screen Height as width and height of the image in draw() method.

```
batch.draw(anim.getKeyFrame(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), true), 200, 200,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Keep in mind that different different screen sizes with different aspect ratios might make your image look bad. To avoid that, you can use a Camera or a ViewPort to keep the aspect ratio while scaling.

Comment: You copied my answer and even the code I posted literally word-for-word...lol...That's an interesting tactic.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that your answer was same as mine. I will delete it for your convenience.

Comment: I don't care, I just thought it was funny.